# Drawing a 2D rectangle with SharpDX

Tags: c#, directx, 2d, directx-9, sharpdx

How to draw a plain red 2D rectangle with SharpDX?

- I have a [SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device available from a library](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/blob/master/Capture/Hook/DXHookD3D9.cs#L260) that sets up a Direct3D v9 device for me, so I'm hoping to be able to use that?
- [Found a tutorial on how to use Direct2D1 to draw a basic rectangle](http://english.r2d2rigo.es/2012/07/04/basic-direct2d-drawing-with-sharpdx/), but the code seems to be dependent on a Direct3D11 device, which I don't have - I need to be able to get the job done without Direct3D11 and without Direct3D10

  ```
  unsafe int PresentHook(IntPtr devicePtr, SharpDX.Rectangle* pSourceRect, SharpDX.Rectangle* pDestRect, IntPtr hDestWindowOverride, IntPtr pDirtyRegion)
  {
      _isUsingPresent = true;

      SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device device = (SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device)devicePtr;

      // How to draw rectangle here?

      if (pSourceRect == null || *pSourceRect == SharpDX.Rectangle.Empty)
          device.Present();
      else
      {
          if (hDestWindowOverride != IntPtr.Zero)
              device.Present(*pSourceRect, *pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride);
          else
              device.Present(*pSourceRect, *pDestRect);
      }
      return SharpDX.Result.Ok.Code;
  }
  ```

Comment: You don't need a Direct3D11 GPU to be able to use it. Direct3D has something called Feature Levels, which means that it will run D3D11 but with only the features available for your GPU. So, unless you're running Windows XP, you'll be able to run it. If you want, open `Run...` and type `dxdiag`. Then look for `DirectX version`. If it's DirectX 11 or more, then you're good to go.

Comment: @LHLaurini the thing is I have a SharpDX.Direct3D9.Device available for me to use from the library, how can I use that? ( i dont have SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device )

Comment: Sorry, I'm good at using DirectX with native code. I'm not much into the managed side. So someone else is gonna have to answer you that. Did you try to run that DX11 code? Sorry, I'm very dumb when it comes to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could draw a sprite using something like the following:

```
// Be sure to only initialise these only once (or as needed)
// not every frame.

//use relative path
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filename = dir + @"\image.bmp";
var _mytext = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromFile(device, filename);
var _sprite = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Sprite(device);

float posLeft = 10f;
float posTop = 10f;
var pos = new SharpDX.Vector3(posLeft, posTop, 0);
var color = new SharpDX.ColorBGRA(0xffffffff);
_sprite.Begin(SharpDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.AlphaBlend);
_sprite.Draw(_myText, color, null, null, pos);
_sprite.End();
```

Loading a texture this way will create a square texture, if the device capabilities support it then you can specify the dimensions when you load the texture, e.g.

```
var _myText = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromFile(device, filename, imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height, 0, Usage.None, Format.A8B8G8R8, Pool.Default, Filter.Default, Filter.Default, 0);
```

Otherwise you can scale the X and Y appropriately within the transform:

```
// Get image dimensions
Size imageSize;
using (var img = Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    imageSize = img.Size;
}
// Calculate scale to get correct image size
var transform = SharpDX.Matrix.AffineTransformation2D(1f, 0f, Vector2.Zero);
// Calculate width scale
if (imageSize.Width <= 128)
{
    transform.M11 = (float)imageSize.Width / 128f; // scale x
}
else if (imageSize.Width <= 256)
{
    transform.M11 = (float)imageSize.Width / 256f; // scale x
}
else if (imageSize.Width <= 512)
{
    transform.M11 = (float)imageSize.Width / 512f; // scale x
}
else if (imageSize.Width <= 1024)
{
    transform.M11 = (float)imageSize.Width / 1024f; // scale x
}
// Calculate height scale
if (imageSize.Height <= 128)
{
    transform.M22 = (float)imageSize.Height / 128f; // scale y
}
else if (imageSize.Height <= 256)
{
    transform.M22 = (float)imageSize.Height / 256f; // scale y
}
else if (imageSize.Height <= 512)
{
    transform.M22 = (float)imageSize.Height / 512f; // scale y
}
else if (imageSize.Height <= 1024)
{
    transform.M22 = (float)imageSize.Height / 1024f; // scale y
}

_sprite.Transform = transform;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this code works mostly except for having a strange issue in that it stretches the image to be taller (to be similar height as is the width, even though the source image is not a square) - see https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/issues/27

Comment: Updated to include scaling (assuming an image that is no larger than 1024 on any dimension)

Comment: Another option for the size, is specify it when loading the texture (assuming the device capabilities support non-square/pow2 textures):

var _myText = SharpDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromFile(device, filename, imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height, 0, Usage.None, Format.A8B8G8R8, Pool.Default, Filter.Default, Filter.Default, 0);

Comment: tried the second option on one device and it worked perfekto. thanks again!